# Intersection point of two independet lines in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code to find the intersection point value of two independent lines , but I am confused that how to obtain the value of the intersection point , till now I have coded :

```
y = [2.63 8.12 13.01 21.87 35.19 58.49];
x = [200 400 500 600 800 1000];
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot([200, 1000], [10, 10]) % this [10, 10] is a straight line
hold off
```

I want to find the meeting point of plot(x,y) and Straight line , Can anyone give me hint for this Thanks :)

Comment: Your question asks about `Cp` and `VisOfA`, but your code has neither...

Comment: sorry I forgot to amend the code, I changed my variable to x and y for easily understandable :)

Comment: Are both `x` and `y` always monotonically increasing? And the crossing line is always horizontal?

Comment: Where do those points come from? Is there an equation to generate them?

Comment: No all these values are fixed

Comment: All these points are constant values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The x-coordinate at which the monotonically increasing piecewise linear curve `plot(x,y)` crosses `v` is given by:

```
interp1q(y,x,v);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is the formula JakubT was assuming for:

```
yIntersect = 10;
dy = diff(y);
dx = diff(x);
i=find(diff(y > yIntersect));
xIntersect = x(i)+dx(i)*(yIntersect-y(i))/dy(i);
-->
xIntersect =  438.45
```

Of course this is not production code.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very elegant solution, but you could, for each pair of consecutive elements of x and y (e.g., [8.12 13.01] and [400 500] being the second such pair), take the equation of the line passing through these two points, compute intersection with your crossing line (I assume that you have/can get the analytical formula for that one?) - and for each such pair of points, you check if the intersection actually happens between these two boundary points - if so, you have both the equation of the line passing through these two points as well as the equation of the crossing line, which yields the point of intersection.

Comment: Beat me to it. X is about 438.4458 for a y of 10 (y = 0.0489x - 11.44) ish   for the line segment 400,8,12 -> 500,13.01:)